# Sort sql result by occurence of a set of keywords

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting, keyword-search

I'm trying to do a little search engine for my website.
First of all, user type in some keywords and go to result page that use this code :

```
$result = array();
$keyword_tokens = explode(' ', $keywords);
$keyword_tokens = array_map(
    function($keywords) {
        return mysql_real_escape_string(trim($keywords));
    }, 
    $keyword_tokens
);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM search_table WHERE concat(title, description) LIKE '%";
$sql .= implode("%' OR concat(title, description) LIKE '%", $keyword_tokens) . "%' ORDER BY instr(description, '$keywords') DESC, instr(title, '$keywords') DESC";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

This code allows to search for keywords requested by user and sort by $keywords, so by the full exact string of group of keywords...

What I'm trying to do is to order results by the most occurence of each keyword.
For example, if a row of my sql result contains 5 keywords and other one 3 etc.. the 5 keywords should come up first. I am searching to sort my results by the more keywords matching.

Hope everything is understandable...

Help will be really appreciated !

Comment: Perhaps take a look at fulltext indexes

Comment: i didnt get your question ??..if a user type the keyword and the most typed result should come first ??.is that ur qus ?

Comment: Hi, user choose $keywords in form that is sent to the search page. I am searching to sort my results by the more keywords matching.

Comment: a fulltext index is probably the easiest way to accomplish this, or you can build a dynamic `order by` as below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lovely thing about MySQL, depending on your point of view. It treats data how it thinks you want it to be treated.  `1 + '1'`? pretty clear you want to treat the string like a number, so it happily performs the addition for you.

Works for boolean operands too (just have to watch the operator precedence).  `(a like '%foo%') + (a like '%bar%')` recognises a numeric context, treats the boolean result `true` as `1` and the boolean result `false` as `0` - essentially counting the keyword matches for you.

How can you use that? Take your `where` clause, replace all the `or` with `+`, and make sure each individual `like` statement is wrapped in parenthesis, then `order by` it.

eg:

```
order by (concat(title, description) like '%keyword1%') 
  + (concat(title, description) like '%keyword2%') desc
```

You can accomplish something similar using a `fulltext index`, but the weighting can be a little weird. Syntax for that would be:

```
create fulltext index idx on search_table(title, description)
```

^^ just do that bit once.

```
select *
  from search_table
  where match(title, description) against ('keyword1 keyword2 ...')
  order by match(title, description) against ('keyword1 keyword2 ...') desc
```

This has the severe bonus of being far less annoying to construct a query for.

[Here's a proof of concept for you](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/00ce1/19) that demonstrates both methods. (albeit only against a single column - but it gets the point across)