# drupal query sorted by keywords occurrence in matching result

Tags: php, sql, mysql, drupal, drupal-7

With big help from @Fky & especially @Syscall I managed to change a drupal query to search within 3 tables instead of two and to add conditions as well as keyword split and removal of whitespaces.

[drupal sql conditional clauses for multiple tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49676437/drupal-sql-conditional-clauses-for-multiple-tables/)

I would like the results 1) to be ordered by keywords occurrence of the matching results and then 2) sorted by title in ASC.

Ie. searching for "banana apple orange" to return:

- banana orange
- apple
- banana
- orange

I managed to order by title but can't figure out how to **sort by keyword occurrences** first?

```
$term = strip_tags(drupal_substr($_POST['keyword'], 0, 100));
$terms = explode(' ', $term); // split using ' '
$terms = array_map('trim', $terms); // remove unwanted spaces
$termsfiltered = array_filter($terms);
 $or = db_or();
  foreach ($termsfiltered as $term) {
    $or->condition('fd.field_detailed_question_value', '%'.db_like($term).'%', 'LIKE');
    $or->condition('fb.body_value','%'.db_like($term).'%' , 'LIKE');
    $or->condition('n.title','%'.db_like($term).'%' , 'LIKE');
    }
 $query = db_select('node', 'n');

$query->fields('n');
$query->range(0,20); //LIMIT to 15 records
$query->orderBy('title', 'ASC'); //ORDER BY title
$query->leftJoin('field_data_body' , 'fb', 'fb.entity_id=n.nid');
$query->leftJoin('field_data_field_detailed_question' ,'fd', 'fd.entity_id=n.nid');
$query->condition($or);
$query->condition('n.status','1');
$stmt = $query->execute(); // execute the query (returns the "statement" to fetch).
```

I found one question [Sort sql result by occurence of a set of keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30273092/sort-sql-result-by-occurence-of-a-set-of-keywords) that mentions

> Take your where clause, replace all the or with +, and make sure each
>   individual like the statement is wrapped in parenthesis, then order by it.

I also saw an example of using **$query->addExpression**...

Would that be the right approach/how to do it with drupal query? Help, please :)

Update: Or **combine orderby with COUNT** somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked answer seens to be the right way to do this.

Creating the `ORDER BY` statement for Drupal query could be done like this:

```php
$term = strip_tags(drupal_substr($_POST['keyword'], 0, 100));
$terms = explode(' ', $term); // split using ' '
$terms = array_map('trim', $terms); // remove unwanted spaces
$termsfiltered = array_filter($terms);

$order_array = [] ; // Create an empty array to create the string
$or = db_or() ;
foreach ($termsfiltered as $term) {

    // Or condition
    $or->condition('fd.field_detailed_question_value', '%'.db_like($term).'%', 'LIKE');
    $or->condition('fb.body_value','%'.db_like($term).'%' , 'LIKE');
    $or->condition('n.title','%'.db_like($term).'%' , 'LIKE');

    // Order by array (add the concat of each fields)
    $order_array[] = '(concat(title, fd.field_detailed_question_value, fb.body_value) like \'%'.db_like($term).'%\')';
}

$query = db_select('node', 'n');
$query->fields('n');
$query->range(0,20);
$query->orderBy(implode('+',$order_array), 'desc'); // Dynamic order by
$query->leftJoin('field_data_body' , 'fb', 'fb.entity_id=n.nid');
$query->leftJoin('field_data_field_detailed_question' ,'fd', 'fd.entity_id=n.nid');
$query->condition($or);
$query->condition('n.status','1');
$stmt = $query->execute(); // execute the query (returns the "statement" to fetch).
```

The adds are :

- `$order_array = [] ;` before the loop
- `$order_array[] = '(concat...)` inside the loop
- `$query->orderBy(implode('+',$order_array), 'desc');` changed

Note that you could prevent errors by using (or something like that) :

```
if (empty($termsfiltered)) { return "No matches."; }
```

---

Another thing. Using `$_POST` is not a good practice in Drupal. If you come from a form, you should use `$form_state['values']['keyword']` instead of `$_POST['keyword']`: See [this example](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/howtos/create-a-custom-user-registration-form-with-fapi-d7).

---

**edit**

```php
$term = strip_tags(drupal_substr($_POST['keyword'], 0, 100));
$terms = explode(' ', $term); // split using ' '
$terms = array_map('trim', $terms); // remove unwanted spaces
$termsfiltered = array_filter($terms);

$order_array = ['title'=>[],'question'=>[],'body'=>[]] ; // Create an empty array to create the string
$or = db_or() ;
foreach ($termsfiltered as $term) {

    // Or condition
    $or->condition('fd.field_detailed_question_value', '%'.db_like($term).'%', 'LIKE');
    $or->condition('fb.body_value','%'.db_like($term).'%' , 'LIKE');
    $or->condition('n.title','%'.db_like($term).'%' , 'LIKE');

    // Order by array (add the concat of each fields)
    $order_array['title'][] = '(title like \'%'.db_like($term).'%\')';
    $order_array['question'][] = '(fd.field_detailed_question_value like \'%'.db_like($term).'%\')';
    $order_array['body'][] = '(fb.body_value like \'%'.db_like($term).'%\')';
}

$query = db_select('node', 'n');
$query->fields('n');
$query->range(0,20);
$query->orderBy(implode('+',$order_array['title']), 'desc'); // Dynamic order by
$query->orderBy(implode('+',$order_array['question']), 'desc'); // Dynamic order by
$query->orderBy(implode('+',$order_array['body']), 'desc'); // Dynamic order by
$query->leftJoin('field_data_body' , 'fb', 'fb.entity_id=n.nid');
$query->leftJoin('field_data_field_detailed_question' ,'fd', 'fd.entity_id=n.nid');
$query->condition($or);
$query->condition('n.status','1');
$stmt = $query->execute();
```

Comment: thanks Syscall, the search results, unfortunately, is not listing yet first the rows where multiple keywords were found in. 
For example, the first two results don't contain one of the keywords.

Comment: @Markus Sorry, I don't understand something. How could don't contain one of the keywords because there is the condition to filter the result? Do you mean that you only display the title, and you want to show most matches in the title?

Comment: i just realised my thinking mistake (drunk too much coffee hehe), you're right, the search also goes through the additional fields / body that won't show in my result as it only prints the titles :) 
Could i prioritise the ones most occurrences matching 1) in the title and then 2) field_data_field_detailed_question 3) field_data_body ?

Comment: better probably would be 1) most occurrences title 2) any matches in title 3) most occurrences detailed_question 4) most occurrences in data_body . This way the results will first display what matches the title being output, and everything after that may relate to the search term

Comment: or other way arround 1) most occurrences title 2) most occurrences detailed_question  3) any matches in title 4) most occurrences in data_body

FYI - detailed_question contains basically alternative phrases of the same question title, where the body contains the answers (thus it's the least priority as I would expect much more results being returned for that).
I'll wait for your update and try to follow it, perhaps I can also then try to change it arround within  `$order_array[] =`.

 understand this order is defined in `$order_array[] =` , I'll wait for your update and try to

Comment: @Markus You can add more than one `$query->orderBy()`. Ex: `$query->orderBy('title','asc');$query->orderBy('status','desc');` will sort by title asc, then by status desc.

Comment: @Markus I've updated the answer. Please see the "edit" part (not tested). I show you another to do this. I think you could find a way to do what you want with this.

Comment: yay, you're my hero, works brilliantly. I will try to turn it around to see the different ordering results re UX.
I tried also re $Post `$term = strip_tags(drupal_substr($form_state['values']['keyword'], 0, 100));` but not working yet, i think i need to declare $form_state in the function first?
`function faq_search_find(&$form_state) {` as per example but didn't help yet.

Comment: @Markus Nice :) Yes, the "submit" function, named as same as your form plus "_submit" : `FORM_NAME_submit(&$form, &$form_state){ ... }`. See the linked example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168417/discussion-between-markus-and-syscall).